# Find a one-to-one correspondence between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N$ - {1}

Tags: functions

Prove that your function is one-to-one and onto the given codomain

A friend wrote this for this problem and I dont understand what they do for the onto part of the proof. Why can y be written as x+1. And is this correct.

F:  $\mathbb N$ $\rightarrow  \mathbb N$ - {1} F(x)=x+1

pf. Let y $\in$ $\mathbb N$ - {1} then y can we written as x+1 for some x in $\mathbb N$ then we have f(x)=x+1=y Thus y $\in$ Rng(F) So F is onto  $\mathbb N$ - {1}.

Let x1, x2 $\in$ $\mathbb N$ Assume F(x1)=F(x2) then x1+1=x2+1. So x1=x2 Then F is one-to-one. 
There f is a one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: Does $\mathbb N$ contain $0$? Some books have $0\in\mathbb N$, others do not.

Comment: The natural numbers start at 1 and go to positive infinity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to word the onto part:

Let $y \in \Bbb{N} \smallsetminus \{1\}$.  Then $y - 1 \in \Bbb{N}$ and $F(y-1) = y - 1 + 1 = y$, so $y$ is in the image of $F$ and $F$ is onto.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in \mathbb{N} - \{ 1 \}$. Then, $x \geq 2$. So, $x - 1 = z$ for some $z \geq 1$ (i.e $z \in \mathbb{N}$). Hence, $x$ is of the form $z + 1$ where $z \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, $F$ is onto, because $F (z) = x$.

Answer (score 1):

I will consider $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3...\}$. The given example is correct, indeed, it is both one-to-one and onto. If we show that there exist an element $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x)=y$ for every $y \in \mathbb{N}-\{1\}$, then we are done. Clearly, $x=y-1$ is okay. It remains to show that $x\in \mathbb{N}$. Since $y>1$, it follows that $x=y-1>0$ as desired. We are done. Note that, actually we have shown that range($f$)=$\mathbb{N}-\{1\}$.